# How can I interleave Bulk transfer and Interrupt probing?

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a huge bulk tranfer to a real time USB device, but I would like to receive some interrupts at the same time.
It looks like the bulk is stalling the interrupt probing, and even with a perpetual interrupt probing loop they get "stuck", and I get a few interrupts after each bulk, but not everything in the queue and all the new ones are stuck (generated after the end of the bulk).

At the theoretical level javascript is visibly mono-thread, and the bulk transfer seem to be in the main thread albeit its non-blockig-friendly API (it freezes the browser). So I don't even know what I'm supposed to do. Web workers can't access the "chrome" object.

Is there some demo code for that somewhere ? I can't find any non-trivial uses of the chrome USB api on google.

It's very difficult to post code do a custom device, but the thing is there: https://github.com/nraynaud/webgcode/blob/gh-pages/webapp/index.js#L110

Comment: Sounds interesting. USB transfers are not supposed to interfere with each other. Could you please [file a bug](http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/?token=&role=&continue=https%3A//code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry.do) specifying the Chrome version and your device, and cc it to ikarienator@chromium.org (which is the engineer of the USB API)?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like filling a bug without having understood what the API is meant to do first. I think I need support for now.